# invalid syntax running Anaconda python Hello World in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I installed the "Visual Studio Code" application on windows 10, and went to: View - Command Palette, selected "Python-select interpreter" and chose "Python 3.6.5 64-bit base Conda", which referenced an installation of Anaconda Python installed by default in a subdirectory of a Visual Studio Community Edition installation I already had installed on the same machine (I think it was installed at the same time as the Visual Studio).

Then I created a one-line Python .py file, containing:

print("Hello World")

and run it by right-clicking and selecting "Run Python File in Terminal"

But I get syntax errors in the output, as follows.

What am I doing wrong?

```
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

> > > "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Anaconda3_64/Scripts/activate"
> > >       'C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Anaconda3_64/Scripts/activate'>>> conda activate base
> > >         File "", line 1    conda activate base
> > >                        ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> > >       "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Anaconda3_64/python.exe" c:/FILES/IB_API_Dev/Octopus/Untitled1.py
> > >         File "", line 1
> > >           "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Anaconda3_64/python.exe" c:/FILES/IB_API_Dev/Octopus/Untitled1.py
> > >                                                                                           ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: To add, when I first installed "Visual Studio Code", it by default ran the Python file in Windows Powershell.
To fix this, I went to File - Preferences - Settings
and pasted:

terminal.integrated.shell.windows

into the text field that appears on the right-hand side.

This caused a new paragraph to appear, with a text field with:

C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

I changed this to:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Anaconda3_64\python.exe

Comment: Ah, it turns out that the terminal.integrated.shell.windows configuration should be the "shell" upon which the Python executable is to be run. Not the Python executable itself.

I have changed the configuration to:

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

and it now works.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, it turns out that the terminal.integrated.shell.windows configuration should be the "shell" upon which the Python executable is to be run. Not the Python executable itself.

I have changed the configuration to:

C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe

and it now works.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run your python from with the python executable from the powershell terminal simply by specify your your conda virtual environment as the interpreter like so:

Open VS code.
Type ctrl+shift+P to open the command pallet.

Enter "python:select interpreter" into the command pallet

You should see your conda environments listed as options, select the conda environment you created and want to use

[image]

The Powershell prompt will look like this

[image]

You can also execute python via conda env in the terminal right click on the python file and select " Python: Run Python File in Terminal"

See the section on Terminal Windows here
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment